# Are two IActorRef pointing to the same actor always equal?

Tags: akka.net

Assume I have two `IActorRef` pointing to the same actor but obtained from different sources:

One actor reference was obtained during local creation of an actor:

`var actorRef1 = system.ActorOf<MyActor>("myActor");`

Later this actor reference was passed to a remote actor, and after the same actor reference was returned back (as an `actorRef2` for example).

**Are the two actor references test for equality?**

`Object.Equals(actorRef1, actorRef2); // true???`

Or another case: two `IActorRef` were received from different remote systems, and pointing to a same actor on another remote system.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This question was answered via gitter chat. But ill post it here as well for posterity.

IActorRef's are equatable, they are compared via their actorpath and UID. So even if 2 actorrefs are acquired through different means, they will still be equal if they point to the same actor.